# How to make Bootstrap drop down menu options to hide after i click one of <li>?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap drop down menu i want to hide the drop down options when i click one of them.
For now when i click one of the options i still see the options.
I need to do so in CSS only without javascript.
Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Smgv/
Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify : you want the dropdown to work without JavaScript ? Because your demo is using the JS plugin.

Comment: @Sherbrow yes , and i want to know a way to hide the drop down after clicking one of them.

Comment: Maybe you could start by providing the CSS-only powered dropdown. The example you are giving IS using javascript.